# Function numpy.apply_along_axis unexpected result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to code a function to convert a 2D numpy array to Mathematica matrix syntax. However, I have found some unexpected behavior of the **numpy.apply_along_axis** function.

This is a piece of code to show this strange behavior

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[-5,6,-7,6,0],[-5,-3,-9,-1,0],[1,-4,0,-4,-4],[4,0,-3,-4,3]])
func=lambda x: '{' + ','.join(x) + '}'
A=A.astype(str)
print(np.apply_along_axis(func,1,A))
print([func(row) for row in A])
```

Output:

```
['{-5,6,-7,6,0}' '{-5,-3,-9,-1,' '{1,-4,0,-4,-4' '{4,0,-3,-4,3}']
['{-5,6,-7,6,0}', '{-5,-3,-9,-1,0}', '{1,-4,0,-4,-4}', '{4,0,-3,-4,3}']
```

It seems that the function `func` is not applied correctly to rows 1 and 2 of array `A`.

```
Python version: 3.6.9
OS: Ubuntu Linux 18.04.4 LTS
Numpy version: 1.13.3
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is convenient when writing an iteration over several dimensions, but it does not improve speed.  And as you found, returning the correct `dtype` can be a problem.  It guesses the `dtype` from a test calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this has to do with the type of the output array (which is a string). After converting your first output into a string, `numpy` seems to define its type based on the length of the first string: `<U13`. All subsequent outputs are truncated at that length. Test it as follows:

```
In [20]: b = np.apply_along_axis(func,1,A)
In [21]: b
Out[21]:
array(['{-5,6,-7,6,0}', '{-5,-3,-9,-1,', '{1,-4,0,-4,-4', '{4,0,-3,-4,3}'],
      dtype='<U13')
```

As you have already indicated in the question, there are ways to solve this without using `np.apply_along_axis`. For instance continuing with your approach, you can say:

```
output = [func(x) for x in A]
```

The `in` operation returns one row at a time for a 2D numpy array, so your output will be a list of strings:

```
['{-5,6,-7,6,0}', '{-5,-3,-9,-1,0}', '{1,-4,0,-4,-4}', '{4,0,-3,-4,3}']
```

Comment: Thank you, I now understand what's going on. Although I'd found an alternative, I wanted to know the reason for that behavior.